# Please help me understand Analytic Density $\lim_{\sigma \to 1^+}\frac{1}{\zeta(\sigma)}\sum_{n \in A} \frac{1}{n^{\sigma}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, definite-integrals, summation, riemann-zeta

$d (A) = \lim_{\sigma \to  1^+}\frac{1}{\zeta(\sigma)}\sum_{n \in B} \frac{1}{n^{\sigma}}$ for $B \subset \Bbb{N}$.  So clearly this limit is $0$ for reciprocally summable (convergent) $B$.

My goal is to prove that $\frac{1}{\zeta(\sigma)}$ can be replaced with $\sigma - 1$ in that formula using Abel Partial Summation.

My understanding is that the limit is taken "from the right" over the reals because of the $\to 1^+$.

Abel's Partial Summation is:

> For any divergent sequence $\lambda_n$ of real numbers.  Let $f(x)$ be a $\Bbb{C}$-valued continuous, differentiable function & let $A(x) = \sum_{\lambda_n \leq x} \alpha_n$ for some complex numbers $\alpha_n$.  Then:
>   $$\sum_{\lambda_n \leq x} \alpha_n f(\lambda_n) = A(x)f(x) - \int_{\lambda_1}^x A(u)f'(u) \, {\rm d}u$$

What I've got so far is:
If $B$ is finite, then this is clearly true as then the limit with $\sigma - 1$ substituted in is $0$.

So let $B$ be infinite, then the divergent sequence we need is staring us in the face.  Let $\lambda_1 \lt \lambda_2 \lt \dots  = B$.

Fix $\sigma$ and let $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^{\sigma}}$. Define $A(x) = \sum_{\lambda_n \leq x} 1$ ie. $\alpha_n = 1$ for all $n$.   Then by Abel's partial summation we have:

$$ \sum_{\lambda_n \leq x} f(\lambda_n) = \sum_{\lambda_n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^\sigma} = \frac{\sum_{\lambda_n \leq x} 1}{x^{\sigma}}  + \int_{1}^x \frac{\sigma \sum_{\lambda_n \leq u} 1}{u^{\sigma + 1}} \, {\rm d}u.$$

Then I'm stuck.

Comment: Isn't it much simpler to use $\lim\limits_{\sigma \to 1^+} (\sigma-1)\zeta(\sigma) = 1$? Then $$\frac{1}{\zeta(\sigma)}\sum_{n\in B} \frac{1}{n^\sigma} = \frac{1}{(\sigma-1)\zeta(\sigma)}\cdot (\sigma-1)\sum_{n\in B} \frac{1}{n^\sigma}$$ shows that the existence of either limit implies the existence of the other, and the two limits are equal if they exist.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer.  I'll use that fact.  But how do you prove that $\lim (\sigma - 1) \zeta(\sigma) = 1$ ?